# Making separate schema compilation work with JAXB 2.2

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, xsd

I am desperately trying to make seperate schema complilation work with JAXB 2.2 and the JAXB2 Maven Plugin 0.8.3. I have followed the [official documentation](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Separateschemacompilation) but it does not reveal how an appropriate XSD should look like.

Note that episode files are generated by default through the parent.

I have the following project layout:

```
parent
   |-- model-a
   `-- model-b (depends on model-a)
```

`model-a.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="urn:net.sf.michael-o:model-a" xmlns:tns="urn:net.sf.michael-o:model-a"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:complexType name="ItemRequest">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:NCName" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Fragment from the POM:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-model</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>src/xsd</schemaDirectory>
        <generatePackage>net.sf.michaelo.model_a</generatePackage>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now here is `model-b.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="urn:net.sf.michael-o:model-b" xmlns:tns="urn:net.sf.michael-o:model-b"
  elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:model-a="urn:net.sf.michael-o:model-a">

  <xs:import namespace="urn:net.sf.michael-o:model-a" />

  <xs:element name="PartRequest" type="model-a:ItemRequest" />
</xs:schema>
```

Eclipse's XML catalog has been fed with the URI of import namespace already.

Fragment from the POM:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>generate-model</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <schemaDirectory>src/xsd</schemaDirectory>
            <useDependenciesAsEpisodes>true</useDependenciesAsEpisodes>
            <episodes>
              <episode>
                <groupId>net.sf.michael-o.jaxb-jaxws-testing</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-model-a</artifactId>
              </episode>
            </episodes>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.michael-o.jaxb-jaxws-testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-model-a</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Unfortunately, this fails with:

```
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/D:/workspace-4.2/jaxb-jaxws-testing-parent/jaxb-model-b/src/xsd/model-b.xsd{8,62}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/workspace-4.2/jaxb-jaxws-testing-parent/jaxb-model-b/src/xsd/model-b.xsd; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 62; src-resolve: Name "model-a:ItemRequest" kann nicht als "type definition"-Komponente aufgelöst werden.
```

The fact is pretty obvious, `model-a.xsd` is not available but isn't it the whole point of having episode files instead of the real schema files? By providing the original file makes this absurd. This issue applies to `wsimport` too where I want to import a schema file (JAXB model) which is built in a seperate JAR.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Because both xsd files are in the same directory you have to add schemaLocation in `model-b.xsd` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="urn:net.sf.michael-o:model-b" xmlns:tns="urn:net.sf.michael-o:model-b"
  elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:model-a="urn:net.sf.michael-o:model-a">

  <xs:import namespace="urn:net.sf.michael-o:model-a" schemaLocation="model-a.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="PartRequest" type="model-a:ItemRequest" />
</xs:schema>
```

If modifying the file is not possible jaxb plugin can read the location of xsd files [from a catalog](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Usingcatalogs). However I did not managed yet to make it work with catalogs.

Comment: Alex, I am aware of this solution but it is actually the opposite to the one I want. I do not want to provide a schema location but work with the namespace only. The bigger problem is that I am using this constellation with is `wsimport` and the situation is even worse. The actual issues are described in [JAXB-514](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-514) and [JAX_WS-368](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-368). And yes, I am using catalogs as a workround for `wsimport` but am not satisfied with.